# Gentle word or phrase meaning ignorantly happy?

Tags: phrase-requests

You know the phrase ignorance is bliss? I want to tell someone — but nicely — that the reason they're not worried about something is that they just don't know the details.

Something like, *I hate to break it to you, but you're in a state of ______*. But not *denial* — that's way too active. Same with sticking your head in the sand. A fool's paradise, except I don't want to call anyone a fool. I thought of "you're just not looking behind the curtain", which I guess would work, but I don't think is a common expression.

I know there must be a phrase for this, but I can't think of it.

Comment: "blissful ignorance", perhaps?

Comment: Even _ignorance_ is a little stronger than I want to say. It's not normally considered nice to call someone ignorant.

Comment: Well, take your pick: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/ignorance

Comment: @mattdm In that case, I think "blissfully unaware" does nicely.  "Unaware" isn't as deprecating as "ignorant."

Answer (score 2):

**innocence**, **ingenuousness** or **candor** may fit.

> Definition of "innocence": *simplicity; absence of guile or cunning;
>   naiveté; the ​quality of not having much ​experience of ​life and not
>   ​knowing about the ​bad things that ​happen in ​life*.
>
> Definition of "ingenuousness": *showing innocent or childlike simplicity
>   and candidness*.
>
> Definition of "candor": *quality of being frank, open, kind and sincere*.

Answer (score 1):

> I hate to break it to you, but you're in a state of **obliviousness**.

The word comes to us from the Latin for forgetting, but its connotation is that of forgetting to pay attention, hence heedless, unsuspecting because unobservant.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to break it to you, but you're [naive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/naive).

or in noun form

The person is a [naif (or naïf)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/naif)

Answer (score 0):

You might say your friend has her "[head in the clouds](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+head+in+the+clouds)" (if you're looking for a phrase).

Answer (score 0):

**starry eyed**?

> : happy and hopeful about something, in a way which prevents you from
> thinking about the bad things about it [Cambridge Idioms Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/starry-eyed)
>
> *I hate to break it to you, but you're in a state of starry-eyed-ness.*